# Summarize years 2010-2013 display detail of 2014 and 2015

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm new to crystal reports 2011 and I'm trying to develop a report that shows the monthly detail for years 2014 and 2015, and only summarizes years 2010-2013.  I have the year as my grouping and I"m able to see all 6 years data summarized when I hide the drill down, but I want to show my customer the monthly data from 2014 and 2015 in detail.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways this can be done:

1. Group on both year & month. In the "section expert" dialogue, define a formula to conditionally suppress the monthly details for appropriate years, e.g., `{table.year} < "2014"` (assuming year is a string, change as needed.
2. Define your own formula and then group on that custom formula, e.g.,:

`if {table.year} < "2014" then {table.year} else 
{table.month} & " " & {table.year}`

The second one also presumes your values are stored as strings, you can use `totext()` to convert non-strong values if necessary. Option 1 is probably easier to present nicely, Option 2 might give a greater level of flexibility for future use of the rpt as a template with arbitrary grouping, though might still require multiple groups and conditional suppression to have it display exactly as desired, but these should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I used the first option as described in the first comment and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 groups, one by `year` and one by `month` and write supress condition of month group like when year < 2014 then supress.

```
if year<2014
then true
else false
```

Comment: Accept anyone of the answers so that others can use it